# Moment of a unimorph cantilever

Tags: beam, moments

I know as a general rule that the moment is the integral of stress multiplied by cross-sectional area (gives force) with the perpendicular distance from force, as mentioned in the [lecture notes](https://homes.civil.aau.dk/jc/FemteSemester/Beams3D.pdf) :

[image]

Now, I'm confused with two similar equations of moment mentioned in two papers.

In the [paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10667857.2020.1751470) " Modelling and analysis of a piezoelectric unimorph cantilever for energy harvesting application", we have a unimorph, a cantilever that consists of one upper piezoelectric layer and one lower inactive elastic layer, as shown in the figure below:

[image]

In the paper, the moment at an arbitrary coordinate x along the cantilever beam with a given
length L, is calculated as:

[image]

(taking into consideration that the stress $\sigma$ depends on the strain $\varepsilon$ and electric field $E$ thats directed along z_axis)

My problem is that I don't see the cross-sectional area multiplied here, there's only dz.

In another [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0924424712001264), we also have a unimorph:

[image]

And the moment of each layer separatley is:

[image]

where $T$ is the stress, and it is multiplied by cross-section but not with the perpendicular distance which may be $z$.